# Unity UI закрепление объекта на 1 слое

Tags: unity3d, ui

Здравствуйте, использую "Unity UI" для создания интерфейса приложения. Соответственно, все объекты интерфейса, являются дочерними объектами Canvas-а.
Так же у меня все кнопки являются динамичными, они постоянно удаляются и создаются новые. Все мы знаем, что чем ниже UI объект находиться в "Hierarchy" тем значение его слоя выше остальных и он отображается по верх всех остальных объектов в сцене. (На самом деле, все дело в порядке отрисовки, для меня объяснение с слоями более привычное) Как зафиксировать один из объектов, что-бы он постоянно отображался поверх всех остальных даже свеже заспавненных? В голову пришла только одна мысль: перемещать объект в Hierarchy на нижнюю позицию при помощи скрипта. На мой взгляд это немного костыльно. Может в самом UI можно как то назначить слой, или что то еще? Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Ну, логичнее, на мой взгляд, выделить для создаваемых объектов отдельного родителя внутри канваса, который будет в иерархии выше, чем тот объект, который у вас должен быть всегда последним.
В отрыве от конкретной реализации, конечно, трудно понять, что именно вам нужно, но это, в любом случае, решаемо.

Answer (score 0):

Вообщем нашел только такое решение: "my_object.transform.SetAsLastSibling();" Перемещает "my_object" в конец списка в Hierarchy.
Ссылка на официальные доки Unity: https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/UICanvas.html